# How to create rpm without building anything?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I have a pile of already compiled binaries, placed under proper locations - how can I automagically create an RPM package from that with a proper meta-information, i.e. version, packager, package name, etc?

The tree may look like:

```
/tmp/fake_root/usr/bin/foo
/tmp/fake_root/usr/lib64/libbar.so
```

Comment: I think you aren't asking this the right way. The question should have been "how to build an rpm without editing .spec file".

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to move files around, package the files as .tgz or .tar.gz, replicating the filesystem structure in it.
Then just use [togo](https://github.com/genereese/togo) to build an rpm without bothering with .spec files.

NB: some advanced rpmbuild features are not available through togo